# Summing all keys in the leaves of a tree

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, tree, complexity

My program takes 35 sec to run example 2. How can I make my program faster?

```
def sum_keys(K, inputs, count=1):
    A, B, M, L1, L2, L3, D, R = list(map(int, inputs))
    x = ((A*K)+B)%M
    y = ((A*K+2*B)%M)


    if K < L1 or count == D:
        my_list.append(K)
    elif L1 <= K < L2:
        sum_keys(x, inputs, count + 1)
    elif L2 <= K < L3:
        sum_keys(y, inputs, count + 1)
    elif L3 <= K:
        sum_keys(x, inputs, count + 1)
        sum_keys(y, inputs, count + 1)

    return sum(my_list)


def read_input(inputstring):
    inputs = inputstring.split()
    A, B, M, L1, L2, L3, D, R = list(map(int, inputs))
    x = ((A*R)+B)%M
    y = ((A*R+2*B)%M)

    if L1 <= R < L2:
        return sum_keys(x, inputs)
    elif L2 <= R < L3:
        return sum_keys(y, inputs)
    elif L3 <= R:
        sum_keys(x, inputs)
        return sum_keys(y, inputs)

my_list = []
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(read_input(input()))
```

Comment: Why did you edit out the description of what this code does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dislike your duplicate, near C&P, functions.
The differences between the functions are:

- One splits the string.
- One doesn't append to the list.
- One uses `R` the other `K` to calculate `x` and `y`.

This means you can reduce the amount of code.
If you make a function that changes `R` to `K` and splits the string,
and you make a change to the other function to not add to the list on the first call.

You also want all `A`, `B`, etc and your `my_list` to be in this second functions scope.
This means a closure is perfect!

You should also generate all the keys before calling `sum`.
I done a profile of you code a significant amount of time was spent in `sum`.

You can also reduce your ifs.
If you change `K < L1` to just test against that, you can then test only against the upper limit on all the other ifs.

This should result in something like:

```
def read_input(input_string):
    A, B, M, L1, L2, L3, D, R = map(int, input_string.split())
    keys = []
    def inner(K, count):
        x = (A * K + B) % M
        y = (A * K + 2 * B) % M
        if count == D:
            keys.append(K)
        elif K < L1:
            if count != 0:
                keys.append(K)
        elif K < L2:
            inner(x, count + 1)
        elif K < L3:
            inner(y, count + 1)
        else:
            inner(x, count + 1)
            inner(y, count + 1)
    inner(R, 0)
    return sum(keys)

import cProfile
cProfile.run('read_input("717 244 2069 280 300 450 20 699")')
print(read_input("717 244 2069 280 300 450 20 699"))
cProfile.run('read_input("31 17 43   5 15 23   5   30")')
print(read_input("31 17 43   5 15 23   5   30"))
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
>     return sum(my_list)
> ```

You don't need to calculate the sum every time.  Do it just when `count` is `1`:

```
if count == 1:
    return sum(my_list)
```

You have a recursive function, but your function doesn't care what itself returns.  All it cares about is the side-effect: `mylist.append(K)`.  Just changing that (without any other changes) made the second example take **less than a second.**  It would be best to return `my_list` and let whatever is calling the function decide if it wants the sum.

In two places you say:

> ```
> A, B, M, L1, L2, L3, D, R = list(map(int, inputs))
> ```

You don't need to convert to a list just to iterate.  That is what `A, B, M, ... = ...` does.  Just use `A, B, M, ... = map(int, inputs)`.  That prevents the unnecessary storage of the numbers in memory.

---

Enough about efficiency.  Let's talk about other things.

Your naming is not ideal.  How does someone looking at your program know what `A`, `B`, `M`, etc. are?  They are just letters.  To tell you the truth, I have no idea what this program is doing.  If you had more descriptive names, it would be easier for future readers (possibly including you) to read the code.  [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide, recommends `snake_case` for normal variables.

It is better not to use global variables.  I would suggest passing `my_list` as an argument to `sum_keys()` instead of relying on the existence of a global variable.

Comment: thanks now my program is faster, but I'm using python 3 and without converting to list I'm getting an errror

Comment: TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @Joe: It gives no errors for me.  It's true that a `map` object is not subscriptable, but we aren't trying that.  Are you doing a test with `map(...)[...]`?

Comment: yes that was the error

Comment: its working with map(int, inputs)